# Insert into highly nested document MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This how the DB is looking like :-

```
{
"courses" : [
       {
        "course" : "Btech",
        "semesters" : [
            {
                "sem" : 1,
                "subjects" : [ ]
            },
            {
                "sem" : 2,
                "subjects" : [ ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "course" : "MBA",
        "semesters" : [
            {
                "sem" : 1,
                "subjects" : [ ]
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to insert a subject(c++) in btech course in sem 1 which would make it look something like this :-

```
 {
    "courses" : [
           {
            "course" : "Btech",
            "semesters" : [
                {
                    "sem" : 1,
                    "subjects" : [
                        "subject" : "C++" // i want to add this 
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "sem" : 2,
                    "subjects" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "course" : "MBA",
            "semesters" : [
                {
                    "sem" : 1,
                    "subjects" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

so far i have written this code :-

```
app.get('/insertSubject', async function(req, res)
{

    const subject = new Subject({
        subject : req.body.subject // req.body.subject = btech
    })
    await Padhlo.updateOne(
        {"courses.course": "Btech" , "courses.semesters.sem": 1},
        { $addToSet : { "courses.semesters.$.subjects": subject } },
        function(err)
        {
            if(!err)
            {
                res.status(200).send("OK");
            }
            else
            {
                res.status(404).send(err);
            }
        }
        )
});
```

but it is giving me this error :-

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cannot create field 'semesters' in element
```

Please help me and tell me where am i going wrong.I am new to MongoDB and i am currently using MongoDB : 5.0.1 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$[]` in your `$addToSet` for multiple positional element

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $addToSet: {
    "courses.$[c].semesters.$[s].subjects": {
      "subject": "C++"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "c.course": "Btech"
    },
    {
      "s.sem": 1
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qD03ePTf87m)

[Official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with----) for identifier is $[]

Comment: This is inserting subject in MBA course also i want to insert subject into Btech course only  i am updating question how the db is looking like after this query

Comment: @Siddharth sorry my bad. The code is updated to use identifier for correct matching

Comment: I have also added the official document link for the identifier usage in $[] operator