# how to update value in a nested array mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query

I want to update all documents in my collection that have a specific value that resides inside a nested array that is structured like this:

```
[{
  "_id": "1",
  "arrayX": [
    {
      "id2": "123", 
      "arrayY": [
        {
          "colour": "blue",
          "size": "small"
        },
        {
          "colour": "red",
          "size": "small"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "id2": "12345", 
      "arrayY": [
        {
          "colour": "blue",
          "size": "small"
        },
        {
          "colour": "purple",
          "size": "small"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

In this case, I need to update the value **"blue"** to **"white"** in the 2 elements that are presented in the example above.

I came up with something like this but it's not working:

```
db.collection.update(
   { arrayX.$.arrayY.$.colour: "blue" },
   { $set: { "arrayX.$.arrayY.$.colour" : "white" } },
   { upsert: false }
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into highly nested document MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570945/insert-into-highly-nested-document-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), to update specific element in nested array and `$[]` to update all elements,

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "arrayX.arrayY.colour": "blue" },
  {
    $set: {
      "arrayX.$[].arrayY.$[c].colour": "white"
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "c.colour": "blue" }
    ]
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3yHhZuBYhj8)