# How can Update a Nested array in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```js
let data = [
    {
        "_id": '101',
        "name": 'category_1',
        "subcategory": [
            {
                "_id": '201',
                "name": 'subCategory_1'
            },
            {
                "_id": '202',
                "name": 'subCategory_2',
                "subsubcategory": [
                    {
                        "_id": '301',
                        "name": 'subsubcategory_1'
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": '302',
                        "name": 'subsubcategory_2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I change subsubcategory name ?

Comment: If the first `subcategory` object has a `subsubcategory` array you can try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vZKtho3-dSD).

Comment: Expanding on @J.F. 's comment, you can also filter on the subCategory name :[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GwENCcNX1u5)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to update value in a nested array mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615353/how-to-update-value-in-a-nested-array-mongodb)

Comment: I have found the solution. Thank you so much.